# Enviando variáveis no Ajax para o PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Usando o php faço uma busca no BD e envio os dados para o AJAX via JSON:

```
echo json_encode(array('sucesso'=>true, 'mensagem'=>'Dados inseridos com sucesso','idservico'=>$idServico));
```

No AJAX eu manipulo as variáveis e agora preciso enviar a variável idserviço para a view.
Para isso eu criei input id='idservico', no meu arquivo html(.php), e no Ajax eu atribuo o valor

```
msg = $.parseJSON(msg);
$('#idservico').val(msg.idservico);
```

Em meu arquivo html preciso fazer uma nova busca, sem que haja um refresh na página.
Minha dúvida é como eu faço para capturar um valor no AJAX, enviar para uma nova requisição PHP?

Já tentei armazenar em cookies no Ajax para depois ler no PHP mas não sei se fiz certo.

gravando no AJAX: `$.cookie("idservico",msg.idservico);`

Lendo no PHP: `$_COOKIE['idservico];`

Meu codigo JQuery:

```
$('#abrirServico').click(function () {
    // - Requisitamos os valores dos campos...
    var data  = $("#data").val();
    var idcliente = $("#idCliente").val();
    var idcarro = $("#idCarro").val();
    var page = 'grava_servico.php';
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'html',
        url: page,
        beforeSend: function () {
            $("#abrirServico").html("Salvando os dados");
        },
        data: {data:data, idcliente:idcliente, idcarro: idcarro},
        success: function (msg) {
            msg = $.parseJSON(msg);
            if(msg.sucesso == true){
                alert(msg.mensagem);
                // exibe o formulário para adicionar novas peças
                $('#itensServico').css("display","block");
                //atribui o valor do idservico para ser usado na hora de salvar na tabela peca_servico
                $('#idservico').val(msg.idservico);
                $.get('new.php', {'idservico': msg.idservico});    
            } else {
                alert(msg.menssagem);
            }
            $("#abrirServico").html("Serviço Aberto");
            $("#abrirServico").attr('disabled', true);
            $("#buscarCliente").attr('disabled', true);
            $("#resetCliente").attr('disabled', true);
            $("#buscarCarro").attr('disabled', true);
            $("#resetCarro").attr('disabled', true);
        },

    });
})
```

Comment: Porque não envia via GET ou via POST?

Comment: Não dá... GET e POST fariam um refresh na página

Comment: Não fariam não é GET ou POST dentro do Ajax, a não ser que você queira manter o idservico para as proximas navegações.

Comment: Não preciso manter o idservico nas próximas navegações. Tem algum exemplo de como fazer isso?

Comment: Algo como `$.get('pagina.php', { 'idservico': $('#idservico').val() })` irá enviar o id pego anteriormente para suposta proxima requisição AJAX (sem paginação)

Comment: como eu capturo a variável idservico na página php? Eu fiz <?php echo $_GET['idservico'] ?>, mas não deu certo.

Comment: É porque fez algo errado no envio do GET. Sem ver o seu código JS eu não vou conseguir saber aonde foi a falha.

Comment: editei minha pergunta com o código jquery

Comment: Você só colocou o `$.get('new.php', {'idservico': msg.idservico});` aleatóriamente, não é assim que se usa ajax, não tem nem como saber se new.php recebeu a variavel, você tem que aplicar o `.done` e o `.fail` para pegar as respostas das requisições HTTP do Ajax. Exemplo: `$.get('pagina.php', { 'idservico': $('#idservico').val() }).done(function (resposta) { alert(resposta); }).fail(function () { alert("Erro"); });`, assim vai executar e você vai saber se deu certo no back-end

Comment: o código que me enviou caiu no .fail. Como devo receber no back-end?

Comment: faz assim `.fail(function (a, b) { alert([a, b]); });` e me diz o que aparace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É fácil jovem, esta é sua requisição:

```
$('#abrirServico').click(function () {
// - Requisitamos os valores dos campos...
var data  = $("#data").val();
var idcliente = $("#idCliente").val();
var idcarro = $("#idCarro").val();
var page = 'grava_servico.php';
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'html',
    url: page,
    beforeSend: function () {
        $("#abrirServico").html("Salvando os dados");
    },
    data: {data:data, idcliente:idcliente, idcarro: idcarro},
    success: function (msg) {
        msg = $.parseJSON(msg);
        if(msg.sucesso == true){
            alert(msg.mensagem);
            // exibe o formulário para adicionar novas peças
            $('#itensServico').css("display","block");
            //atribui o valor do idservico para ser usado na hora de salvar na tabela peca_servico
            $('#idservico').val(msg.idservico);
            $.get('new.php', {'idservico': msg.idservico});    
        } else {
            alert(msg.menssagem);
        }
        $("#abrirServico").html("Serviço Aberto");
        $("#abrirServico").attr('disabled', true);
        $("#buscarCliente").attr('disabled', true);
        $("#resetCliente").attr('disabled', true);
        $("#buscarCarro").attr('disabled', true);
        $("#resetCarro").attr('disabled', true);
    },

});
```

})

agora você atribui uma variável para este teu id serviço, assim:

```
meu_id_servico = $('#idservico').val(msg.idservico);
```

repare que a variável é global.Uma dica o Ajax trabalha de forma `assíncrona` ou seja se você colocar dois `ajax`, os dois irão começar a ser executados juntos então você precisa esperar o primeiro acabar para pegar o valor de `meu_id_servico` e enviar para outra requisição certo? Como fazer isso?

Simples, basta você colocar essa outra requisição dentro de `.done()` do primeiro `ajax`. ou seja ela irá ser executada quando a primeira estiver pronta. (em outras palavras quando sua variável `id_serviço` estiver preenchida).

no final da sua requisição deixe ela assim:

```
        $("#resetCliente").attr('disabled', true);
        $("#buscarCarro").attr('disabled', true);
        $("#resetCarro").attr('disabled', true);
    },

}).done(function() {

       //aqui o código da sua nova requisição    
       $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "url_nova.php",
            **data: { meu_id_servico : meu_id_servico},**
            cache: false,
            beforeSend: function() {

            },
            complete: function() {

            },
            success: function (retorno) {

            },
            error: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });

});
```

Comment: Cara, show de bola sua explicação... Ainda sobre para entender a lógica do assincronismo do AJAX. Eu estava pecando justamente nisso. Deu certo sua explicação.

Comment: hahaha eu tb demorei um tempão pra entender como funcionava, eu li numa pergunta que me passaram